# Flutter only release app is crashing when I push chat screen in firebase Also i have change package name before

Tags: flutter, dart

Am trying to release my apk and just changed the `com.example` package name to my own `com.[companynamehere].[appname]` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file and `app/build.gradle` file, however now my app stops working as soon as I run it.

Any idea what might be the problem? Is there anywhere else I need to change the package name?

I'm also using firebase and I generated a new `google-services.json` file with the new package name.

Answer (score 0):

Update your package name in android>src>main>kotlin>Mainactivity.kt

Hope it will work. If it doesn't work then another solution is to search your old package name on the entire project and replace them with the new package name. In this case, VSCode will help you to do this just with a few clicks.